# Problem with a function checking "if" statements

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to design a simple password system. It works with a function checking 3 if statements. The problem is that even when the password is correct, it does not run the first if statement.
It seems like the variable `entry` is never equal to the variable `password`, but I don't know why.

```
##user input space
entry=Entry(top,bd=5)
entry.pack(side=LEFT)

##actual password to be set
password="abc"

number_of_guesses=0

##function to check user input
def r():
    global entry,password,number_of_guesses

    number_of_guesses+=1

    if entry==password and number_of_guesses<5:
        root=Tk()
        text=Text(root)
        text.insert(INSERT,"You shall pass\nAttempts used:")
        text.insert(INSERT,number_of_guesses)
        text.pack()

    elif number_of_guesses<5 and number_of_guesses>0:
        root=Tk()
        text=Text(root)
        text.insert(INSERT,"Wrong password\nYou used ")
        text.insert(INSERT,number_of_guesses)
        text.insert(INSERT,"/5 attempts")
        text.pack()

    elif number_of_guesses>=5:
        root=Tk()
        text=Text(root)
        text.insert(INSERT,"Wrong password\nYou used ")
        text.insert(INSERT,number_of_guesses)
        text.insert(INSERT,"/5 attempts")
        text.insert(INSERT,"\nAccess denied\n")
        text.pack()
```

Comment: Can you print `entry` and `password` before the if statement?

Comment: `entry` is of type `Entry` and `password` is of type `str`. How can these ever be equal? Did you mean `entry.get() == password`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to get text from the entry as follows:

```
if entry.get()==password and number_of_guesses<5:
```

To explain, you were comparing an Entry object (which is a set of data and functions) to a text. You have to specify that you want to use the text value by `.get()`. For more about Entry widget please refer to [Documentation of Entry Widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly.
Can you explain to me why this is different from what I wrote at first?

Comment: @Simone: I added a short explanation.